# Linkedin - "Not enough permissions to access: GET-search /companySearch" error

Tags: python-3.x, linkedin-api

I want to get the recent posts of some company's using Linkedin developer APIs ? but even though i have the access token with the respective scopes it still throws "Not enough permissions to access: GET-search /companySearch"  error

And also i have the marketing or sales permissions.

i am trying microsoft linkedin API documentation. to display latest posts of a company i need company id, i am trying to get the company id using linkedin APIs

```
import requests

url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/companySearch?q=search&query=LinkedIn%20Corporation"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer AQWnucFOeJ2x6QxaXBZKL4sBvvIfZUeK-Sc-XPnB1tLsnVzmAOjhw05u-6tnFV7TPysPHLmCuphOUK119lUT4wi61I0v40-cUipJFqZX6CIL6s-X3mVYJf63ej3lpukAbMiWvD9bfrpkYMKCFNzU37QYULXQ1XXM9weyj59lHiJHLFsjD2RbDk7LErYsQLQRDkArtxHbUXih8etxiAN14G5rLhSPBTQLsCHCMQElwFausxDhAbOKw_3R7Nl9ewT_7MAai0MNtQBudhpzQRS_rqC3zf8b-gQBuYMXeCQwXB7guOY4TjkW-KUFB7j9hsVu2SMoc2Q5KGZxnRUpHbSjqAI8rLLgSw',
  'Cookie': 'lidc="b=OB19:s=O:r=O:a=O:p=O:g=3576:u=5:x=1:i=1677756407:t=1677758225:v=2:sig=AQECaqQELXcYLqhksRlr8XgfO9SWLwyA"; bcookie="v=2&366e73db-f8b1-4b59-8740-b4035784e287"; lang=v=2&lang=en-us; JSESSIONID=ajax:1499692230832704324; PLAY_SESSION=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJkYXRhIjp7ImZsb3dUcmFja2luZ0lkIjoiOE5WaW04cFFTajZPUkZTak1MRlU1dz09In0sIm5iZiI6MTY3NzczMjIyNiwiaWF0IjoxNjc3NzMyMjI2fQ.rV0Gh8ax6G1CTfxAmaz6KvddaPPu7H21GjqUJzddJBw; lang=v=2&lang=en-us'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```